# PHP imagecreatefromgif is not creating animated gif from path

Tags: php, gd, gif

I am trying to get animated gif image from path. However I am getting gif that is not animated

```
$im = imagecreatefromgif($path);
$newFilePath = app()->basePath("public/memes/") . $newname .'.gif';
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
imagegif($im, $newFilePath);
imagedestroy( $im );
return $newFilePath;
```

Comment: See the "User Contributed Notes" here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php

Answer (score 5):

[manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php) - "When reading animated GIF files into memory, only the first frame is returned in the image resource pointer."

Take a look at http://phpimageworkshop.com/tutorial/5/manage-animated-gif-with-imageworkshop.html